# Mirroring HTML page print

Tags: html, css, browser, printing, mirror

I need to print an HTML page, but it needs to get out mirror.
Is there any way to set up an HTML page to be printed mirror?
It could be a solution with CSS or in your browser settings!

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @AAnkudovich said, use his CSS, but create a separate CSS file called Print.css and reference it into your page. That way you can control all of your printing styles separate from the rest of your styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to css.

```
html {
 direction:rtl;
}
```

also what could be done is surrounding all content you want by a div with a class like so

```
<div class="content-to-be-mirrored">
  //actual page content
</div>
```

and only add the suggestion above to that class

```
.content-to-be-mirrored{
  direction:rtl;
}
```